# How to read line of HTML as string in c#

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to get a page title from page source of different pages. But lets say some pages have title like this:

```
&quot;This is an example,&quot; ABC.
```

It has some html in it like """. If i use string in c# to get this title i get the whole thing and while displaying it displays it like above which is wrong. Is there any way to ignore or to take into account html values in c#?

I am also using htmlagilitypack so anything in that will do too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `WebUtility.HtmlDecode` to decode html, link on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webutility.aspx):

```
WebUtility.HtmlDecode("&quot;This is an example,&quot; ABC.");
```

just use:

```
using System.Net;
```

The result will be: "\"This is an example,\" ABC."

You also can use `HtmlEntity.DeEntitize` in `HTML Agility Pack`:

```
HtmlEntity.DeEntitize(string text)
```

Comment: So i will have to download WebUtility? Is there anything in HTML Agility Pack to do this kind of thing?

Answer (score 0):

You don't know what you can find in the page title. Sometimes is a whole mess there. My suggestion is to get the string as it is and process it before to show/save it.

In this case, the solution is simple: replace the

```
&quot;
```

with corresponding char.

Each time you read a HTML document to extract some tags, take care to tags never closed. If the user forget to close the title tag... you'll get in that line the whole page!

Comment: I mean i can do that for this particular string. But if i run 1000 queries i will get lot of different characters how will i replace them all? There should be an easy way to convert right?

Comment: The possibilities are limited. Read about special html characters: http://www.utexas.edu/learn/html/spchar.html and implement some replacement method(s).